# Crystal Report: Parameter damages the whole report

Tags: crystal-reports

While using Crystal Reports I have encountered a strange bug, that repeats itself already with a number of my reports.

I still didn't fully get how I can replicate it, but usually it goes as follows:

1. I add a parameter of any type to an existing report document, however it doesn't appear in a parameter prompt at all.
2. After I change parameter order in the Parameter Fields Section, my Parameter disappears and instead I see a duplicate of another parameter in a parameter list, and in the "Set Parameter Order"-Window I see this duplicated parameter as [ParameterName, ParameterName]. If I save the document in this moment and try to reopen it, CR crashes.
3. If I try to load this document in Vstudio with CREngine, the code exits with this message:

   > Access violation

Here is a picture of what is happening:

[image: pic]

Comment: You may also want to post this on the [SAP Community website](https://community.sap.com/).

Comment: what Crystal Reports version do you use? what is the type of parameter? Is it craxddrt.dll error? Please, attach [Debug Diag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210) log

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not being prompted for the new "test" parameter is that it is not used by the report for anything.

The rest of the behavior is indeed strange. Consider removing the '@' character from the name of the first parameter to see if that fixes it.
If some of those parameters are from a stored procedure, perhaps your report is simply out of sync with the data source. Do ***Database, Verify Database...***